# Why does eval(parse(text=string)) give shorter output for object of class aov?

Tags: r, parsing, eval

Why does this...

```
B.aov2<- eval(parse(text=StringforEvaluation))
summary(B.aov2)
```

produce a less detailed report than this...?

```
res.aov2 <- aov(DV ~ IV1*IV2+Error(Participant/(IV1*IV2), data = AnovaAnalysisData))
summary(res.aov2)
```

---

Reproducible data, per request of a user. I know it's weird, but I'm making a user-friendly stats program for my students. Now that I've posted the "reproducible code" it wants me to provide more data. Now, I didn't originally post this code because I thought it was a bit much and my general coding sucks.. My question still stand.. Why does one give me a short crappy, unhelpful output, and the other one provide exactly what I want...I ran the same command:

```
library(tidyverse)

DV <- c(1,1, 5,6, 1, 2, 7, 7, 1, 4, 9, 9)
IV1 <- c("A","B", "A", "B","A","B", "A", "B","A","B", "A", "B" )
IV2 <- c("C","C","D","D", "C","C", "D","D", "C","C", "D","D")
Participant <- c("A", "A", "A", "A", "B","B","B","B","C","C","C","C")
IV3 <- "no_data" #remove the word "no_data" and add c("A","B", "C", etc.. )
IV4 <- "no_data" #remove the word "no_data" and add c("A","B", "C", etc.. )

##### You have to tell the computer if the variable is within! 
IV1_iswithin <-"Y"
IV2_iswithin <-"Y"
IV3_iswithin <-"N"
IV4_iswithin <-"N"

####### Your JOB is DONE 

data <- data.frame(DV,Participant,IV1,IV2)

#Grouping the dataframe 

data %>%group_by(IV2, IV1)%>% #subsetting the data set to calculate 4 different stats
  mutate(MAD = median(abs(DV-median(DV))*2.5*1.4826))%>% #calculates 4 differnet mad numbers
  mutate(MADLL = median(DV)-MAD)%>% #cacluates UL of MAD, pipe output to next command
  mutate(MADUL = median(DV)+MAD)%>% #calculates the LL of MAD
  mutate(OutlierPresent = ifelse(DV<MADLL | DV>MADUL, NA, DV))%>% #Creates NA values if it is an outlier 
  ungroup()%>% #converts back to big data set 
  mutate(OutlierPresent = ifelse(DV<MADLL | DV>MADUL, NA, DV))%>% #Creates NA
  mutate(whichgroup <- paste(IV1,IV2))%>%
  mutate(observation = 1:n()) %>%
  {. ->> b }

b %>%
  select(DV,OutlierPresent) %>%
  {. ->> outlierfeedback }
formattable(outlierfeedback)

b %>%
  select(OutlierPresent,IV1,IV2,Participant) %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = c(IV1,IV2), values_from = OutlierPresent, names_sep = "_", id_cols = Participant)%>%
  drop_na()%>%
  pivot_longer(-Participant, names_to = c("IV1","IV2"), names_sep = "_", values_to = "DV")%>%
  {. ->> AnovaAnalysisData }

### Calculating the ANOVA for our outlier free data AnovaAnalysisData

#SettingUpTheListofFixedFactors
FactorModel <- list()
ifelse(length(IV1)> 1, FactorModel<- c(FactorModel, "IV1"), FactorModel<-FactorModel)
ifelse(length(IV2)> 1, FactorModel<- c(FactorModel, "IV2"), FactorModel<-FactorModel)
ifelse(length(IV3)> 1, FactorModel<- c(FactorModel, "IV3"), FactorModel<-FactorModel)
ifelse(length(IV4)> 1, FactorModel<- c(FactorModel, "IV4"), FactorModel<-FactorModel)

#SettingUPTheListofErrorFactors 
ErrorModel <-list()

ErrorModel <- list()
ifelse(IV1_iswithin== "Y", ErrorModel<- c(ErrorModel, "IV1"), ErrorModel<-ErrorModel)
ifelse(IV2_iswithin== "Y", ErrorModel<- c(ErrorModel, "IV2"), ErrorModel<-ErrorModel)
ifelse(IV3_iswithin== "Y",ErrorModel<- c(ErrorModel, "IV3"), ErrorModel<-ErrorModel)
ifelse(IV4_iswithin== "Y", ErrorModel<- c(ErrorModel, "IV4"), ErrorModel<-ErrorModel)


StrStart = "aov(DV ~"
StrFactor<-paste(ErrorModel, collapse='*' )
StrErrorStart<-("+Error(Participant/(")
StrError<-paste(ErrorModel, collapse='*' )
StrErrorEnd<- ("),data=AnovaAnalysisData))")
StringforEvaluation<- paste(StrStart, StrFactor,StrErrorStart,StrError,StrErrorEnd)

B.aov2<- eval(parse(text=StringforEvaluation))

summary(B.aov2)

res.aov2 <- aov(DV ~ IV1*IV2+Error(Participant/(IV1*IV2), data = AnovaAnalysisData))
summary(res.aov2)
```

Comment: please include a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example). We don't have stringforevaluation or your data.

Comment: I appreciate the edit. I was literally doing it and you beat me to it.

Comment: A reproducible example should also load the packages that the code needs. I get exactly the same output for `summary(B.aov2)` and `summary(res.aov2)`.

Comment: `formattable(outlierfeedback)` is not needed in your code for this problem. But, as @Stibu, I get the exact same summary result for both aov's. Also `identical(B.aov2, res.aov2)` returns TRUE so they are exactly the same. You might want to restart your R session. That might help.

Comment: Really!  OMG, NOW IT WORKS FOR ME TOO!  THANKS Y'ALL..